# Difference between Active Users and Retained Users

Tags: google-analytics, flurry, flurry-analytics

Can someone explain me the difference between the 2 APP metrics, Active Users and Retained Users. I am looking at these metrics through flurry API and I am grouping my data at month level. 
I am not able to understand what is my Retained users number mean at a month level.

Comment: Consider asking this at webmasters.stackexchange.org (SO is more about code-related questions).

Answer (score 1):

Retained users plots two lines. The blue line is the number of users who installed the app in a given month, week or year. The green line identifies how many of these users had at least one session with your app in the past week.

The two lines will generally converge for the current month so use weekly or daily views to analyze the current month.